# Why am I not able to change the background color of my bottom navigation bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the background color of my bottom navigation bar to black but yet it's remaining white. What could be causing the issue?

Screenshot of the bottom navigation bar

[image: Screenshot of the bottom navigation bar]

Bottom navigation bar code.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
    iconSize: 30,

    unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
    selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black, size: 30),
    selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
    selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,

    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.door_back_door),
        label: 'Rooms',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        label: 'Search',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.map),
        label: 'Maps',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        label: 'Profile',
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
  ),
```

I've been trying to figure this part out and I can't seem to see the reason of the issue. I'd appreciate any help if possible! :)

Comment: Have you tried to set `backgroundColor: Colors.black`?

Answer (score 1):

Read the description of the `BottomNavigationBar` `backgroundColor`, it says

> If [type] is [BottomNavigationBarType.shifting] and the [items] have
> [BottomNavigationBarItem.backgroundColor] set, the [items]'
> backgroundColor will splash and overwrite this color.

So the solution can be to set `backgroundColor` to one of your `BottomNavigationItem`s and it will apply to the whole `BottomNavigationBar`.

Answer (score 1):

`background color` works only when the `type` is `BottomNavigationBarType.fixed`

If `type` is `BottomNavigationBarType.shifting`, `items` will override this `color`

---

###### BottomNavigationBarType.fixed

[image]

###### BottomNavigationBarType.shifting

[image]